# Difference in rendering an AdaptiveCard in teams desktop, web and mobile app, where a column style is not applied in the fist two. A bug?

Tags: microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

A while ago I made a monitoring flow that reports any state changes, as an adaptive card like shown below. I created the card based on a few examples, I have not deep dived into the AdaptiveCards story.

[image: Previously displayed]

A few weeks ago I was told the adaptive card had lost its colors.

[image: Currently displayed]

What happens is that the style of the column, that would color the background, is not rendered anymore.

I assume an update of the teams has occurred that causes this in the desktop and webGUI version.
My teams for mobile app still renders the card correctly.

Am I doing it wrong?  :-)  Or should I try to file a bug report

Here is the barebone JSON of the card.

```
{
    "type": "AdaptiveCard",
    "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
    "version": "1.2",
    "selectAction": {
        "type": "Action.OpenUrl",
        "title": "Monitoring",
        "url": "https://somewhereon.sharepoint.com/teams/acb123/sub/Lists/mon/AllItems.aspx"
    },
    "body": [
        {
            "type": "ColumnSet",
            "columns": [
                {
                    "type": "Column",
                    "width": "90px",
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "type": "TextBlock",
                            "text": "Applications",
                            "wrap": true,
                            "weight": "Bolder"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "type": "Column",
                    "width": "stretch",
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "type": "ColumnSet",
                            "columns": [
                                {
                                    "type": "Column",
                                    "width": "stretch",
                                    "items": [
                                        {
                                            "type": "TextBlock",
                                            "text": "Testing 123",
                                            "wrap": true
                                        }
                                    ]
                                },
                                {
                                    "type": "Column",
                                    "width": "15px",
                                    "style": "good",
                                    "items": [
                                        {
                                            "type": "TextBlock",
                                            "text": " "
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "ColumnSet",
                            "columns": [
                                {
                                    "type": "Column",
                                    "width": "stretch",
                                    "items": [
                                        {
                                            "type": "TextBlock",
                                            "text": "Testing 456",
                                            "wrap": true
                                        }
                                    ]
                                },
                                {
                                    "type": "Column",
                                    "width": "15px",
                                    "style": "warning",
                                    "items": [
                                        {
                                            "type": "TextBlock",
                                            "text": " "
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "ColumnSet",
                            "columns": [
                                {
                                    "type": "Column",
                                    "width": "stretch",
                                    "items": [
                                        {
                                            "type": "TextBlock",
                                            "text": "Testing 789",
                                            "wrap": true
                                        }
                                    ]
                                },
                                {
                                    "type": "Column",
                                    "width": "15px",
                                    "style": "attention",
                                    "items": [
                                        {
                                            "type": "TextBlock",
                                            "text": " "
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Thanks for any feedback

On the left the view in teams mobile.

On the right on top, the desktop version (1.4.00.26376 64-bit) and below the web teams.

[image: Picture of the 3 Teams versions]

Comment: Could you please share the screenshots from different devices so that it will be easy for us to investigation the issue.

Comment: Can you try the same in [developer preview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/dev-preview/developer-preview-intro#enable-developer-preview)? I am able to repro the issue and it isn't happening when switching to dev preview.

Comment: @ChetanSharma-msft

I added the screenshots to the question. Dark is teams desktop light is teams web. 
The android one has the phone icons below

Comment: @Hunaid Hanfee-MSFT
 
How do I get to that developer preview? 
Does this require modifications of our tenant? 
I fear that will certainly be refused as all is meant to stay as default as possible.(to avoid any compatibility issues)

Comment: Could you please share the Teams Desktop Client version? For developer preview I just wanted confirm if its rendering correctly for you as well.

Comment: I have tested in Teams Desktop v1.4.00.27120 (64-bit)-E and I can see the colors.

Comment: So is it not happening on desktop?

Comment: @HunaidHanfee-MSFT  So an update is on its way then I guess, I see this:
Microsoft Teams Version 1.4.00.26376 (64-bit). It was last updated on 29/09/2021.
The issue is happening on the desktop for me, as well as on the web version. Only the  mobile version works like in the activecard designer.
I believe my company is in charge of the update process on my PC, but I will raise an ticket to inquire.

Comment: We have raised a bug for web client. I will update you on the status. If you still face on desktop. Please keep it posted.

Comment: IT told me to use Windows Update Assistant to bring the machine up2date. But I still have the same (1.4.00.26376 64-bit) version of teams desktop with the above mentioned issue.

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be fixed now and it is working as expected.
Tested in both MS Teams desktop `(Microsoft Teams Version 1.6.00.20269)` and web client.

Example JSON:

```
{
  "type": "AdaptiveCard",
  "body": [
    {
      "type": "TextBlock",
      "text": "Bleed left"
    },
    {
      "type": "ColumnSet",
      "style": "emphasis",
      "columns": [
        {
          "type": "Column",
          "style": "good",
          "items": [
            {
              "type": "TextBlock",
              "text": "Column 1"
            }
          ],
          "bleed": true,
          "width": "stretch"
        },
        {
          "type": "Column",
          "style": "attention",
          "items": [
            {
              "type": "TextBlock",
              "text": "Column 2"
            }
          ],
          "width": "stretch"
        },
        {
          "type": "Column",
          "style": "warning",
          "items": [
            {
              "type": "TextBlock",
              "text": "Column 3"
            }
          ],
          "width": "stretch"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
  "version": "1.2"
}
```

Result:

[image]

Result with the JSON provided in the question:
[image]